# What does equals in ngRepeat do?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What does the equals in the `ng-repeat` attribute value mean?

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people = (people | orderBy: firstname)">
```

instead of doing:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy: firstname">
```

I can't see any examples explaining its use in the documentation for ngRepeat.

Comment: as per my understanding first statement assigning filtered result of (people | orderBy: firstname) to variable people.

Comment: @AnupamSingh So the actual scoped people would change after filtering it? So therefore I'd be correct in saying that another repeater that uses people would already be filtered?

Comment: yes you are correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is usefull for count how many objects were filtered, eg.

```js
function People($scope) {
  $scope.people = [{
    firstname: 'a'
  }, {
    firstname: 'c'
  }, {
    firstname: 'b'
  }, {
    firstname: 'c'
  }]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="People">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in filteredPeople = (people | filter: 'c')">{{person.firstname}}</li>
  </ul>
  Total filtered: {{ filteredPeople.length }}
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

@Krzysztof - There is no requirement of "=" operator usage to show number of objects filtered. It can be done without it. So, you are completely wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <p ng-repeat="x in people | orderBy: 'age'">{{x.name}},{{x.age}}</p> 
    <p>Total Filtered: {{people.length}}</p>
<script>
//Module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$timeout){
    $scope.people = [{name:"Peter",age:15},{name:"Julie",age:28},{name:"Roger",age:17}];

});
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide code that shows how many people are 15 years old